# Pascal incrementing variable names of textboxes

Tags: loops, variables, for-loop, increment, pascal

I am using Arrays for managing my data in and outputs.

My problem is that I need  to i/o from or into textboxes which are continously incremented by 1- So my Array starts at 1 and ends at 31. My textboxes which are  variables and cannot be arrays are named like memo67... - memo97.

Is it possible in a way that I use a tmepcounter? So I wanted to use something like memo(a+66) in a for loop. With this I could fill my textboxes with my array[a] 1 to 31.

Greets

Comment: If you have controls named myctrl1, myctrl2, myctrl3, ..., myctrlN you are doing something wrong. Use an array instead. Also, it is "not" possible to access myctrlK dynamically by "concatenating parts of variable names".

Comment: I am using a tool to create print forms. In this I have got a lot of textfields which I have to have access to input my array contents. The problem here is that these boxes are named memo1, memo2 and so on. So is it possible to have "textbox" arrays which are named memo[1].. memo[2] and so on? Unfortunately as you said it is not possible to concatenate variablenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andreas says, usually arrays are used in such case. But if you like me like the quick copy and past action, you can fill such arrays can be using TComponent features with one single procedure:

```
Type 
   TForm1 = class
              editsset1 : array of tedit;  
             end;



type     TControlDynArray      = Array of TControl;


procedure loadarray (root:tcomponent;var x : TControlDynArray;basename:string;i1,i2:integer);
var l,i : integer;
begin
 l:=i2-i1+1;
 setlength(x,l);
 for i := i1 to i2 do
   begin
     x[i-i1]:=tcontrol(root.FindComponent(basename+inttostr(i)));
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // loads edit1..31 into  editsset1[0] ... editsset[30]
  loadarray(self,TControlDynArray(editsset1),'Edit',1,31);
end;
```

Disclaimer: the above code is pieced together from working code, but I didn't test the endresult

Comment: Yes, this approach is certainly possible (that's why I put "not" within quotes in my comment!).

Comment: My code is working now as I have used something like this: I have to declare once all my Textboxes with my Array elements    mName[1] := M1;
  mName[20] := M20; and can use the Textboxes with mName[1] as I have noticed. So do I understand this correctly that my Array elements are references / pointers to the adress of M1 ?

Comment: Delphi classes are already references/pointers/ so you copy the pointer value stored in M1 into the array.

Comment: Thanks for help. So if I get it correctly:

if I change the values of my array elements, they will be changed in M1 aswell. I am asking this because I guess that my sourcecode works like this, but I am not sure if this is the answer.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes. It is just putting references in an array.  It is all straightforward, except for the dynamic array cast in the call, which is the trick to use one routine for many types. The routine is very generic and not dependent on the form, and in one of my personal libs.